# Remove current URL autofill in fetch()

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, fetch

I'm new to web developing and I'm having a bit of trouble with my first website. I'm using Django REST Framework on the backend for the API and React.js on the frontend. I'm on URL `127.0.0.1:8000/course/1` and I'm trying to make a call to the API to retrieve the information of course 1. The API is in `127.0.0.1:8000/api/courses/1`, so I use:

```
fetch('localhost:8000/api/courses/1')
```

The problem is that it apparently makes a GET request on `127.0.0.1:8000/course/1/127.0.0.1:8000/api/courses/1` which obviously doesn't exist. The problem is that for some reason it automatically appends the argument of `fetch` to the current URL. I tried this from the home URL with `fetch('api/course/1')` and it works. What should I do?

This is the complete code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


export class Course extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            course: {}
        }
        this.getCookie = this.getCookie.bind(this);
        this.fethCourse = this.fetchCourse.bind(this);
    }


    getCookie(name) {
        let cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            let cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                let cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }


    fetchCourse() {
        fetch('localhost:8000/api/courses/1', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'X_CSRFToken': this.getCookie('csrftoken'),
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({
            course: data
        }))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }


    UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
        this.fetchCourse();
    }

    
    render() {
        const course = this.state.course;

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{course.name}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Course;
```

The error from the terminal running the server (manage.py):

```
"GET /static/frontend/main.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
Not Found: /course/1/127.0.0.1:8000/api/courses/1
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the `http://` prefix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your fetch URL should be:

```
fetch('/api/courses/1')
```

Always start with forwardslash **/** on local URLs

Comment: I can't believe the answer was so simple lol. Thanks!